# Why do I keep getting a ConflictingCommandException when trying to save my domain object to NEventStore?

Tags: c#, domain-driven-design, cqrs, neventstore

I am using a session to interact with a `CommonDomain.Persistence.IRepository`. My save command is `CommmonDomain.Persistence.RespositoryExtensions:`

```
public static void Save(this IRepository repository, IAggregate aggregate, Guid commitId).
```

Every time I try save the new domain object. I get a ConflictingCommandException  which is a concurrency exception. Is there a common reason that this is caused?

Answer (score 0):

The only time I've seen this error spawned is when the domain object and the associated events do not have the same domain id. Verify you have the same id going to both the event and the object.